# Cannot clear default textbox in codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, onclick, onfocus

I am trying to clear a textbox (which has default text of 'Enter Text') when user clicks on it.

I tried:

```
  txtValue.Attributes.Add("onClick", "if(this.value =='Enter Text') this.value=''");
```

But it just doesn't work. Nothing happens.

Any ideas what's wrong there?

All my textboxes are dynamically generated...could that be the reason?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the HTML5 placeholder attribute?

Comment: Not using placeholder for a number of reasons..also I don't want to clear all the textboxes that has other texts (all my textboxes dynamically created).

Comment: What is generated in the HTML? Do you see the onclick event handler in the generated HTML on the textbox element?

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie - not quite sure how to see the onclick event handler?

Comment: This code is working, I do not know what you expect but as It is, if the rest of the values are correct, then is working. Here is a test http://jsfiddle.net/WbK9G/ and http://jsfiddle.net/WbK9G/1/

Comment: "Not using placeholder for a number of reasons." Do you even know what the HTML5 placeholder does? The same thing you are reinventing. Yes it does not have IE8 support, but there are libraries that add it.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem, viv_acious?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.  The ["onclick" attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) of a DOM element is all lowercase (you have capitalized the "c"):

```
txtValue.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(this.value =='Enter Text') this.value=''");
```